# What does JPA "expect" for non-owned relationships?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am working through ProJPA2 and I am currently at the section on collection mappings.
There is the following example wrt Maps:

[image: onetomany map]

This, to me, is quite confusing text to understand. It raises many unanswered questions. One of them is, if I retrieve a Department using a JPQL query, how is the map employeesByCubicle supposed to be populated? I understand that using "mappedBy" essentially says: "I am not responsible for maintaining this relationship: the other side is, and you will find the relationship at the department field in the Employee entity".

However, this does not satisfy the question: "if you retrieve an instance of Department, how is employeesByCubicle supposed to be populated?"

Is it up to the application (ie developer of the application) to insert code to manually populate collections (such as employeesByCubicle) that are owned by the other side of the relationship? In such a case, one could not and would not expect the employeesByCubicle map to be populated by simply retrieving the Department entities from the DB: and this would be the case *because* the relationship is not owned by Department?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

I have proceeded with trying to implement the example in the book and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly - I am able to get cubicle/employee data persisted but I am getting a "null index column for collection" error when I try to retrieve it using "select d from Department d", which runs off and amongst other things seems to try to pull the data from the EMPLOYEE table:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection: x.y.jpa.entity.Department.employeesByCubicle
```

I have tried adding nullable=true, optional=true, nothing is working.
In the db the CUB_ID column is specified as   `CUB_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL` which is as it should be - I want this column to be nullable. But I cannot make it work so that the data can be selected. Is it a problem with my mappings?

My entity classes, Employee and Department:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;
    ...

    @Basic(optional=true)
    @Column(name="CUB_ID",nullable=true)
    String cubicle;
    ...
}


@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="CUB_ID",nullable=true)
    private Map<String, Employee> employeesByCubicle;        
    ...
}
```

The data in MYSQL:

[image: data]

---

**EDIT2**

I am beginning to think that what I am trying to do may not be achievable; if it is the case that given a `Map<String,Employee>` in Department, then JPA will go to the Employee table and retrieve all employees for a given department, and then for each employee extract the cubicle, and then try to put an entry into the map with `k=cubicleid`, `v=employee`, then perhaps there is no way to tell JPA that if cubicleid is null, do not try to put an entry into the map. 
Is this thinking right or wrong? TIA.

Comment: The exact same way as if it was a List or a Set: since the association is lazy, the map would not be populated at all. On the first access to the map, JPA would load the employees belonging to the department and would populate the map.

Comment: @JBNizet OK location of the map key must be known or specified, correct? So when I have a `@OneToMany Map<String,X>` where X is an entity, either `@MapKey` is used or `@MapKeyColumn`; if the former then JPA expects the key to be X's PK; if the latter is used it specifies the column in X where the map key is found, correct? So in this case JPA expects Employee. Yes?

Comment: Correct. It's a Map<String, Employee>, so it's an association with Employee.

Comment: OK thanks very much. I have updated my question because I have progressed a little further, but I am getting a `null index column for collection` error when selecting from the Department, because there are rows in Employee for which I have not entered a map key value (CUB_ID in this case). I have searched but cannot find anywhere any reference to what I would have thought would be a common use case / problem. Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your object design implies that every employee of a department has a cubicle and that cubicle is unique for the department. Your data isn't consistent with that design. So either fix the data, or change the design.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve in a more generalized sense, is to put a OneToMany Map<String,X> in Y, wherein there is not a map key (ie column value) for every X. Is this possible?  Of course, in JDBC this would be very easy to implement, because you would be manually populating the Map yourself, but is it possible in JPA? If it is simply not possible, then its better for me to know, because I am then wasting my time trying to implement something that cannot be implemented with JPA. Thanks very much.

Comment: No, it's not possible. And it wouldn't be possible with JDBC either. What key would you use for all the employees without a cubicle? Assuming the null key, how would you store alll these employees as a single value in the map?

Comment: You would do what JPA presumably does which is to retrieve all Employees for a Department; but then, insert the (simple) logic: for each Employee, if cubicleId is not null, map.put(cubicleId,employee), otherwise do nothing. You end up with a map of cubicleIds to employees. It is not an unrealistic scenario, and I am surprised it is not possible in JPA but that is that.  Thanks for your help.